# Basic file I/O of a ppm file

Tags: c, file-io, ppm

I'm trying to write a program to read through a .ppm file and keep the data in a struct. To be able to do that though, I need to be able to open the file, which is not working so far. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Can you please take a look at the code and see if you can find out what's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readFile(char *filename);

int main(void)
{
    readFile("myfile.ppm");
    return 0;
}

int readFile(char *filename)
{
    int x = 0;
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(!pFile)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(pFile, "%d", &x);
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This just gives me an "\n" on the stdout. Should I fscanf it into an array rather than an int?

Based on your feedback I edited the code to scanning to two chars:

```
int readFile(char *filename)
{
    char first, second = 0;
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(!pFile)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(pFile, "%c%c", &first, &second);
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("First: %c, Second: %c\n", first, second);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: test the return value from `*scanf`: it should be the number of variables assigned a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format the file starts with a two byte sequence: `P1`, `P2`, `P3` (as Human readable Text - ASCII). So reading this into an `int` will not work. You should read in a `char` (for the `P`) and then another `char` for the number and to find out what format your file is. Then depending on the format take further steps.

Comment: I edited the question based on your feedback. The output: `First: , Second: `

Comment: view your PPM file with something. What are the first two characters?

Comment: yeah, I feel so stupid now.. uploaded a 0 byte ppm file instead of the right one. thanks